# Finding a matrix for least squares with a projection matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}$ be a matrix so the columns are not linearly dependent and let $y\in \mathbb{R}^2$. Find $B\in\mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}$ and $y'\in\mathbb{R}^2$ so the least squares is true, meaning:
$$
\min ||B x-y'||_2^2=\min (Ax-y)^T P_{A} (Ax-y)
$$
where $P_A$ is the projection matrix ($P_A=A\left(A^{T}A\right)^{-1}A^{T}$). I have no idea how to find a proper example. Is there a special thinking I need to follow for that?

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$P_A^T=P_A=P_A^2$$ i.e. it's an ortho-projector. Furthermore $\,P_AA=A$.

Substitute into the RHS to identify the expression on the LHS
$$\eqalign{
(Ax-y)^TP_A(Ax-y)
 &= (Ax-y)^TP_A^TP_A(Ax-y) \\
 &= \left\|P_A(Ax-y)\right\|^2 \\
 &= \left\|Ax-P_Ay\right\|^2 \\
 &= \left\|Bx-y'\right\|^2 \\
}$$
Therefore $$B=A,\qquad y'=P_Ay$$